# How to redirect user after login Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

If my user encounters a controller with my attribute [CustomAuthorize], he is redirected to the login page where he gets his JWT token. But on successful login I want to redirect him to the place where he initially wanted to be(the URL he wrote before was redirected to login  page). what's the best way to save the path?
That's my CustomAuthorizeAttribute:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Login");
                return;
            }

            if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Login");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

In other words, how to know from which request the user came from?

Answer (score 0):

I'be decided to write pass a parameter to Login Controller like this

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {

                var values = new RouteValueDictionary(new
                {
                    controller = "Login",
                    RequestedAddress = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values.Values.First()
                });
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(values);
                return;
            }

            if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Login");
                return;
            }
        }
```

And then to get it like this

```
public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(String RequestedAddress)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```